# PHP: getting data from DB and using while loop

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm new at PHP programming and I have this little problem with WHILE loop:

```
$query=<<<SQL

SELECT paskaita, laikas, savaite, pogrupis, auditorija, destytojas, dalykas, tipas 
FROM paskaitos
WHERE grupe_pav = '$grupe' 
AND sav_diena = '$diena'

SQL;

$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json_output[]=$row;    
    print(json_encode($json_output));
}
```

So I'm getting these results:

Instead of getting one final [...] block I get whole 4 [...] blocks. It's obvious this is problem with WHILE loop, but I can't find way to fix.

```
[{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Paskaitos"}]
[{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Paskaitos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"2","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Olga Subo?","kodas":"FMMMB11503","dalykas":"Skaitiniai metodai","tipas":"Pratybos"}]
[{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Paskaitos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"2","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Olga Subo?","kodas":"FMMMB11503","dalykas":"Skaitiniai metodai","tipas":"Pratybos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"2","laikas":"10:20 - 11:55","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRK-II 203","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Pratybos"}]
[{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Paskaitos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"1","laikas":"08:30 - 10:05","savaite":"2","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 09","destytojas":"Doc. Olga Subo?","kodas":"FMMMB11503","dalykas":"Skaitiniai metodai","tipas":"Pratybos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"2","laikas":"10:20 - 11:55","savaite":"1","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRK-II 203","destytojas":"Doc. Meda Norbutait?","kodas":"STIAB11515","dalykas":null,"tipas":"Pratybos"},{"sav_diena":"Tre?iadienis","grupe_pav":"MKDf - 11\\/1","paskaita":"3","laikas":"12:10 - 13:45","savaite":"","pogrupis":"0","auditorija":"SRA-II 10","destytojas":"Lekt. Ernestas Filatovas","kodas":"FMGSB11505","dalykas":"E-paslaug? technologijos","tipas":"Paskaitos"}]\n
```

All I need is last [...] block that contains eveything. Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get `print(json_encode($json_output));` out of the loop